# Find the sub string from specific character to the next space character using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring, charindex

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET @c = 'This is and example #COIN-XXXX data only'
```

So basically, I want everything after #COIN- to the space i.e.(XXXX only).

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another method is:

```
DECLARE @word varchar(max) = '#COIN-XXXX This is and example data only'
DECLARE @c varchar(100) = '#COIN1-'
DECLARE @CharIndex int = (select CHARINDEX(@c, @word))
if @CharIndex = 0
    select 'No matching word'
DECLARE @firstSpaceAfter_index int = (select CHARINDEX(' ', @word, @CharIndex))
if @firstSpaceAfter_index = 0
    set @firstSpaceAfter_index = len(@word) + 1

SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@WORD, @CharIndex, @firstSpaceAfter_index - @CharIndex),@c, '')
```

Comment: Thanks @Aliasghar, Nice explanation and easy to understand.

Comment: i checked the space existence after the word. if variable @firstSpaceAfter_index is 0 i replace it with max lane +1 to prevent the error you notice

Comment: your welcome.
if it help you, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select left(v.str, charindex(' ', v.str) - 1)
from (select @c as str) x cross apply
     (values (stuff(x.str, 1, charindex('#COIN', x.str) + 5, ''))) v(str);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79aa698fa43455ce9875b3a5d3f410cb) is a db<>fiddle.